# "JMSException: Invalid character '\n' in value part of property"

Tags: java, jms, invalid-characters

I am trying to connect to a JMS server and post a message to the queue.  When I run the Java program that creates a simple MapMessage and inserts it into the queue, I get this exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Invalid character '\n' in value part of property
```

I don't know what "property" it is referring to, because none of the configuration files has a '\n' in any of its values.

The code block that causes this exception is:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Queue queue = (Queue)ctx.lookup("MyQueue");
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

The last line throws the "Invalid character JMSException".

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that is used to connect to this JMS ?

Comment: Which JMS Provider are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache ActiveMQ.  I have an ActiveMQ JMS broker running when I run the Java program creating the JMSException.

Answer (score 0):

MapMessage basically contains data in a Key/Value(or Property Name/Value)pair format. Looks like value of the property is not liked by ActiveMQ JMS client, hence it's throwing exception. Sample code would have helped. You will need to debug further and isolate the line of code that's causing this problem.

---

UPDATE
someone else also has seen similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650656/invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is-javax-jms-jmsexception-in

I suspect the issue is with JNDI parsing code Java 1.8.

Comment: Bit strange though as the simple code is throwing exception. I expected the createConnection method to through exception because of some invalid attribute. The only thing I can suggest you is to check the definition of "ConnectionFactory" in JNDI to see if it has any invalid property.

Comment: Thank you, Shashi.  The odd thing is that the code runs fine when using Java 1.5, but it throws the error when using Java 1.8.  Therefore I suspect that the root cause is either the jndi.properties file or the Java version I am using.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I thought since it works with no problems with Java 1.5.

Comment: I hard-coded the values using some online ActiveMQ documentation as a template.  That way I won't have to set or read properties.  I set the queueName to "com.axeda.integration.ACME.queue", the brokerURL to "tcp://hostname:61616", and the ActiveMQInitialContextFactory name to "org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory", compiled it, and ran it for both systems.  As before, the Java 1.5 run completed, but the Java 1.8 run gave me the same error, even though I am not reading anything from the jndi.properties file.  Will we have to resort to Java 1.7 or earlier to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

With help from my team, I found out what caused the JMSException.  The ActiveMQ log files on each system contain lines with the broker properties.

The broker properties on the server that works (Java 1.5) looks like:

```
ActiveMQ Broker (localhost, ID:<hostname>) started
```

The broker properties on the server that does not work (Java 1.8) looks like:

```
ActiveMQ Broker (localhost, ID:<hostname a>
<hostname b>) started
```

On the latter system the '\n' is between `<hostname a>`, the correct part, and `<hostname b>`, the incorrect part.

That means the server ID property got corrupted, and therefore this was a problem only the system administrator could solve.  Once he reset the server properties to have only `<hostname a>`, and no `<hostname b>`, the program worked as it should.